# Endgame - 2 Rooks vs 2 Bishops

Tags: endgame, rook-endgame, bishop-endgame

How does one checkmate with two rooks when playing against an opponent with two bishops? I am having difficulties with the bishops shutting down my rooks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19882/2-rooks-vs-2-minor-pieces-in-a-pawnless-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19882/2-rooks-vs-2-minor-pieces-in-a-pawnless-endgame)